# How do I get the physical dimensions of a DWG file?

Tags: sbc

How can I get the dimensions from this DWG file? I need the length and width as well the the precise locations of the mounting holes of this SBC (link to ZIP file below).

- http://dn.odroid.com/ODROID-XU/PCB_DWG/XU_MAIN_REV0.3.zip

I've tried pretty hard to find the dimensions myself and this DWG file is the best source of information I've got.

Comment: This file is a real mess (in ACAD 2010 format). Suggest you get a proper drawing from the original source. eDrawing (Solidworks) opens it, but as I said, it's a real mess.

Comment: I assume the real question you have is where you can get dimensions for a part. The DWG file is just the closest you got to finding posted dimensions on the part. Could you share information on the part you're needing dimensions for? No offense but I'm not downloading some random zip file just to figure out what you're trying to dimension.

Comment: FYI, there is an new [Engineering Stackexchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) for questions like this. Unfortunately for you I'm pretty sure it's still in private beta so if you weren't a "supporter" I don't think you can join yet.

Comment: @I.Wolfe The part is PCB board of the XU3.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I tried to open using Solidworks as well but I'm going to try what the guy posted below. Thanks.

Comment: @auldwin I suggest caution because I don't think that's actually made from the final design files- the silk screen in all over the place etc.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's really annoying. How hard is it for a manufacturer to provide simple dimensions. It's like they are trying to provide everything else but the dimensions of the board. How hard can it be for them to do that? They have to make the bloody thing. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to open this file easily using Dasault's draft sight.  It's free and located [here](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/)  I could then easily add dimensions to it.  I suggest you give it a try and don't take the hastily added dimensions in this image below as the final ones.

[image]